# Scrolling test with Jasmine

Tags: angular, scroll, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test an angular Directive that do something on scroll, with Jasmine and Angular.

Here is the directive code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dfScroller]'
})
export class ScrollerDirective {
  @select(['module', 'sessionTimeout', 'showTimeoutWarning']) readonly showTimeoutWarning$: Observable<any>;
  debounceLastAction = debounce(() => { this.actions.updateLastActionTimestamp(); }, 1500);

  constructor(private actions: ModuleActions) {}

  hideToastComponent = () => {
    if (convertObservableToList(this.showTimeoutWarning$)) {
      this.actions.showTimeoutWarning(false);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll') scrolling() {
    this.debounceLastAction();
    this.hideToastComponent();
  }

  @HostListener('click') clicking() {
    this.debounceLastAction();
    this.hideToastComponent();
  }
}
```

And here is the spec file, I am testing a click event and scroll event as well:

```
…
// Test case
describe('Directive: Scroller directive', async () => {
  compileAndCreate();

  it('Should be able to test the scroller directive on click', async () => {
    const debounceLastActionSpy = spyOn(directiveInstance, 'debounceLastAction').and.callThrough();
    const hideToastComponentSpy = spyOn(directiveInstance, 'hideToastComponent').and.callThrough();
    directiveEl.nativeElement.click();

    expect(debounceLastActionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(hideToastComponentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('Should be able to test the scroller directive on mouse wheel', async () => {
    const debounceLastActionSpy = spyOn(directiveInstance, 'debounceLastAction').and.callThrough();
    const hideToastComponentSpy = spyOn(directiveInstance, 'hideToastComponent').and.callThrough();
    directiveEl.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();

    expect(debounceLastActionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(hideToastComponentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

If I comment out the expect part of the scrolling test and the whole click test, I can see the methods covered. But as soon as I add the expect, I have an error message saying that the method were never called.

I already tried a couple thing:
 - Run unit test with Karma, still got the error.
 - Remove the debounce from the debounceLastAction, still got the error.